# sentence type classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, nlp, text-classification

I want to classify the sentences in my dataset as `declarative`, `interrogative`, `imperative` and `exclamative`. Although It can be classified with respect to punctuation marks such as `?`, `!` and `.` but there are many cases and situations that these rules can fail.

In NLP area, is there any model or solution that can be applied to reach the mentioned goal?

Comment: Good question. I don't remember seeing anything like this but it could exist. I'm pretty sure it's not a standard NLP task.

Comment: Yes this is a standard NLP task if you have well-labelled data.